# cannot select from a dropdpwn menu on firefox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using *Java* and *Selenium* to write a test. I have a drop down menu from which I need to select something. This is my code:

```
 Select s= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("blabla")));
 s.selectByVisibleText("theName");
```

it works on *Chrome* but on *Firefox* 47 I get this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: 
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

I know how to handle selecting from drop down menu by other ways, but I need to use `Select` object.

Comment: Have you verified that the XPath is valid on FF? It's hard to help without relevant HTML.

Comment: So did you wait until it's become visible using `WebDriverWait`??

Comment: Try CSS selector instead of xpath. Coz xpath may not be same at all browsers.

Comment: @Jeffs yes the xpath is the same for FF and Chrome and we also used used `wait.unit(...visibilityOfElementLocatedBy(..))` too

Answer (score 0):

Use fluent wait to wait element, chrome is faster:

```
public static void waitUntilElementIsVisible(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) 
{        
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver);
    wait.pollingEvery(250,  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    wait.withTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    wait.ignoring(ElementNotVisibleException.class); //make sure that this exception is ignored
    Function<WebDriver, WebElement> function = new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>()
            {
                public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    System.out.println("Checking for the element!!");                       
                    if(element.isDisplayed() != true)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Target element is not visible");
                    }
                    return element;
                }
            };

    wait.until(function);
}
```

Then you can call it:

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("blabla"));
waitUntilElementIsVisible(el, driver);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WebDriverWait` class to wait for the visibility of the element like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, customTime);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Select s = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("blabla")));
s.selectByVisibleText("theName");
```